# How to combine sass and less files correctly with laravel-mix?

Tags: laravel, webpack, sass, less, laravel-mix

I tried to use both sass ans less dependencies with laravel-mix

webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
mix.sass('resources/sass/app-sass.scss', 'public/css')
mix.less('resources/less/app-less.less', 'public/css');
mix.combine(['public/css/app-sass.css', 'public/css/app-less.css'], 'public/css/app.css');
```

This seems to work, but is combining the compiled css files a good idea? Or is there a better way (that dont create the both files)?

Comment: As a general guideline you can bundle everything in one single file so you can edit them respectively but in the end you'll have one .css file.

Answer (score 0):

I use to combine only files from external libraries(node_modules), that I'll need for all the pages of my project. So, I can easily minify them and call them with only one link.

I also never use sass and less on the same project.